# How to provide a Data.Vector.Unbox instance for StablePtr's in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, vector, ghc, unboxing

I want to use the `vector` package to store unboxed arrays of `StablePtr a`

How can I use the following (or variations thereof):

```
ptr2Int :: Ptr a -> Int
ptr2Int (Ptr a) = I# (addr2Int# a)

stablePtrToInt :: StablePtr a -> Int
stablePtrToInt = ptr2Int . castStablePtrToPtr

intToStablePtr :: Int -> StablePtr a
intToStablePtr (I# i) = castPtrToStablePtr $ Ptr (int2Addr# i)
```

to declare an `Unbox` instance for `StablePtr a`?

Comment: are you sure you don't want to use Data.Vector.Storable instead?, StablePtr's are instances of Storable.

Comment: oh thanx for the hint :) I guess it will do.

Comment: @danvari would u mind writing your answer as an answer so that I can accept it. Btw I assume the memory usage will be the same as with unboxed vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually no need trying to define an Unbox instance for StablePtr. Since StablePtr's are instances of Storable you can just use Data.Vector.Storable instead.